# Laravel: redirecting to a controller@store method redirects to the index instead

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect to PostsController@store but the page redirects to PostsController@index:

In routes.php:

```
Route::Resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::Resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
```

ReviewsController

```
class ReviewsController extends Controller {
    public function store(Request $request) {
        // (do a bunch of stuff)
        return redirect(action('PostsController@store',[$request])); 
    }
}
```

PostsController

```
class  PostsController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        dd('Incorrectly redirects here');
    }
    public function store(Request $request, Post $post) {
        dd('This is where I am trying to redirect to');
    }
}
```

No error or exception occurs. However, once redirected, the url is:

```
http://localhost/laravel2devel/public/posts?POST%20/laravel2devel/public/reviews%20HTTP/1.1%0D%0AAccept:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8%0D%0AAccept-Encoding:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gzip,%20deflate%0D%0AAccept-Language:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20en-US,en;q=0.8%0D%0ACache-Control:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20max-age=0%0D%0AConnection:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keep-alive%0D%0AContent-Length:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20132%0D%0AContent-Type:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded%0D%0ACookie:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InhzN2JiK0FvYnIrUnVoeGZkcGNHOXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMFdrdnluNTdrR3l3OTlrZE9QSDA1WVwvalNoeDhHbG0wUXlvT0NBblRyWDNocFwvMExCZ0dqdVppbjR2M29SdnRmbWRDMkdRc042XC9ib3hrd2xZa1JCTmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjQ0ZmM4YTg4YmIxNTliMGY0MzI0OGMxMjMyZGM0ZDU4ZGM4MTVlMGM2NzVmZWNmM2YzZjI5YWU4OTJhOWM5MGYifQ%3D%3D;%20laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjRCRThcLzdaR3ZaUUZJdTVQcmtVZk5BPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlJYTlFaWk5WZEZQbHdkQzhtalhGbko0dnUzdzN0UjhOM2FLZUJQMkloNkMwdGRjc3VcL3lNUjBaXC9acktrUkxvRzZEWW4rVlY3Q0o2alB3VnJnNEZDdnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImIwMjRlMzIzYWYxNDI5NjEzYmFmZjljMjg4MmFkYzU1MTkzZDVkOWRjM2IwMzZlNTM1MTE2ZWExYTA3NmYyNzgifQ%3D%3D%0D%0AHost:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20localhost%0D%0AOrigin:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://localhost%0D%0AReferer:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://localhost/laravel2devel/public/swords/1%0D%0AUpgrade-Insecure-Requests:%201%0D%0AUser-Agent:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Mozilla/5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1;%20WOW64%29%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20%28KHTML,%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome/48.0.2564.97%20Safari/537.36%0D%0A%0D%0A_token=DeQeCCA8e19IIsxGhouybXiqIFoAMLsQ6sgp5EMF&post_title=asdfdas&user_id=2&reviewable_id=1&reviewable_type=item&post_body=asdfdfas
```

Comment: Try as `Route::post('store', ['as' =>'store' , 'uses' => 'PostsController@store']);`

Answer (score 2):

If you use resource controller then, `store()` method is expected to be called with HTTP POST. If you redirect then it will use GET, so Laravel will call `index()` instead. See [Laravel HTTP Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a route as a resource it will handle the Restful requests to each methods.

A get request to the url will execute the `index()` method. For the `store()` method to execute a post request need to be given. `store()` method is to add the resource.

Please go through the [resource controller documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear about your question but my idea is if you wants store reviews for particular post just use your routes like this

```
Route::Resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::Resource('posts.reviews', 'ReviewsController');
```

then check the **route:list** then you will get the list of routes, i hope you have two tables then use **foreign key** you can archive your goal

i hope this is good tutorial for you [LINK](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/)